# edit:pandas multiline value in ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

If I put something with newlines in cell into pandas dataframe, for example:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[["""aa\n<br>
bb"""], ['bb']], columns=["col"])
```

I get something where all "newlines" are escaped. (html source looks like: <td> aa\n&lt;br&gt;\n\nbb</td>)

Is there way to get table with formatted multiline output in cell?

**edit**:
inspired by firelynx I could use now this:

**edit2**:
html escaping added

**edit3**:
nowrap attribute for td and th tags

```
df=pd.Dataframe(...)  # see definition above
from IPython.display import HTML
import cgi

def escape(a):
    return cgi.escape(a).replace('\n','<br>')

htm='<table>'+\
    '<thead><tr><th></th>'+\
    ''.join(['<th nowrap>'+escape(c)+\
    '</th>' for c in df])+'</tr></thead>'+ \
    '<tbody>'+''.join(['<tr>'+'<th>'+str(r[0])+\
    '</th>'+''.join(['<td nowrap>'+escape(c)+\
    '</td>' for c in r[1]])+'</tr>' for r in enumerate(df.values)])+\
    '</tbody></table>'
#print(htm)
HTML(htm)
```

Answer (score 1):

The ipython notebook formats data for you if you just return values from a cell in the way you do.

To see the actual value, you have to explicitly print it, look here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["""aa\n<br>
bb"""], ['bb']], columns=["col"])
print df.ix[0].col

aa
<br>
bb
```

So nothing is actually wrong, it's just the ipython representation that fails to show the truth.

There are display options to be changed, but nothing that revokes this default behaviour.
The display options are set by, for example:

```
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
```

[Display option reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use one more back slash before "\n"(\\n) to consider "\n" as a new line. also for `&lt;` and `&gt;` check if the pd.DataFrame has any other variable where we can mention the data is of html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) function and set the `escape` parameter to `False`:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['aa<br>bb'], ['bb']], columns=['col'])

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

This will keep Pandas from escaping the `<br>`.
Note however that any HTML code in your table will be rendered (or needs to be escaped manually).